# Changing num lock state on boot, VMWare Player

Tags: boot, vmware-player

For school we have to work with different virtual machines in VMWare Player for some courses. There's CentOS6, there's Ubuntu, there's Windows 7.

The passwords on these machines contain numbers and it's very annoying to have to turn num lock on every time the VM boots to type in the password since I often forget it.

The second problem is to have it remain on after logging in and logging out of user accounts. On Windows 7 I know the registry entry for that, I don't know how to do it in the Linux distributions however.

I've searched the net but most solutions that I found are for VMWare Fusion or something else not equal to VMWare Player.

I would like a detailed answer to this or at least something to help me out already, and I believe other people will also be glad to see this answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily done by adding either the line

```
bios.forceSetupOnce = "TRUE"
```

or

```
bios.bootDelay = "xxxx" (milliseconds, 5000 works fine)
```

to the **.vmx** file in a text editor of choice. This will either force the VM to go into setup on boot once (the line is removed after that) or create a delay long enough for you to press the setup key to enter the BIOS (you may not want this every time). The BIOS has a menu for keyboard options that includes the setting for num lock state on boot.

Source of this information is a VMware KB article: [Accessing the BIOS when the POST screen clears too quickly](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004129).

Comment: Slight syntax error, it should be bios.forceSetupOnce = "TRUE" to enter the BIOS one time.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on VirtualBox and a search brought me to this question, so added an answer anyway for anyone else who experiences the same.  Rather than go to the BIOS, I found a better fix [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=82027#p435733) which removes the feature "*makes the host keyboard lights match those of the virtual machine's virtual keyboard*".

So either:

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage" setextradata "My VM name" GUI/HidLedsSync "0"
```

or amend the `.vbox` file to contain the setting `ExtraDataItem` / `GUI/HidLedsSync` and set it to zero:

```
<VirtualBox xmlns="http://www.virtualbox.org/" version="1.15-windows">
    <Machine ....
    <MediaRegistry>
        ...
    </MediaRegistry>
    <ExtraData>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/HidLedsSync" value="0"/>
```