# Remove irritating numlock popup in vmware player

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-player

I'm running Ubuntu in a VMWare player and whenever my mouse crosses into or out of the VMWare window, a Num Lock On or Off notifier briefly appears underneath it. It's very distracting. How do I remove this? Or how do I just change the num lock status in Ubuntu so that it matches the num lock on the host computer (which will hopefully result in suppression of the popup)?

Here is a video of the problem:

http://screencast.com/t/izygXvk2T

I have a small mac keyboard on my PC and I'll admit I have no clue how or where numlock is on it, either.

For completeness, it's Win 7, Ubuntu 13.04, VMWare player 5.0.2 build-1031769

Comment: Please refer to this link: http://superuser.com/questions/491865/changing-num-lock-state-on-boot-vmware-player - I do not have the required reputation to comment the link, but it will definitely help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the short answer is that you can't directly sync the host and guest environments regarding Num Lock.

However, a couple of alternatives are available:

1. As noted in Rudolph's comment link, change the VM BIOS setting to enable/disable Num Lock at boot in the VM to match the hosts default
2. Manually set the state of guest Num Lock to match the host